# Fail to export redis to different files in express

Tags: node.js, express, redis, export, node-redis

When I npm start the express server and go to localhost:3000/
There will be error message: (node:6984) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The client is closed
The redisClient will be working when I put the createClient() in App.js, however, I want to make connect to the redis once and all files able establish the same connection

"redis": "^4.0.4"
"express": "^4.17.3"

App.js

```
const express = require('express');
const port = 3000;
const { getData} = require('./utils/data');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  getData()
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

./utils/data.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
const redisClient = require('../controllers/redis');

const getData= async() => {
    redisClient.get("getData", async(error, data) => {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        if (data != null) {
            return res.json(JSON.parse(data));
        } else {
            axios.get(`http://api.com`)
                .then((res) => {
                    redisClient.set("getLeague", JSON.stringify(res.data));
                    res.json(res.data);
                });
        }
    });

};

exports.getData= getData;
```

./controllers/redis.js

```
const redis = require('redis')
const redisClient = redis.createClient()
redisClient.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('redis client connected');
});
module.exports = redisClient;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redis NodeJs server error,client is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185436/redis-nodejs-server-error-client-is-closed)

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman The post doesn't solve exporting a connected client on V4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve and able to import client to different modules

App.js

```
(async () => {
  const app = express();
  ...
})();
```

redis.js

```
const { createClient } = require('redis');
const client= createClient();
client.connect();

module.exports = {
    client
};
```